# Bit manipulation 1101 & (~0 << 2)

Tags: bit-manipulation

```
1011 & (~0 << 2) = ?
```

I figured it would be `1011 & 100` which equals to `0`, but the answer says `1000`. Why's this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your word-size, but for "pure" (that is, arbitrary precision) numbers, `~0` is as many 1s as you need, so `~0 << 2` is really `...11100`. That leads to the expected result

```
...0001011
...1111100
----------
...0001000
```

If you were working with fixed-sized 4-bit words, then

```
1011
1100  (~0 == 1111)
----
1000
```

Comment: makes sense now. thanks for clearing it up. So technically `100` for `~0 << 2` is not wrong then?

Comment: It's wrong, unless you are using 3-bit words, but then `1011` doesn't have any meaning (as it has 4 bits).

Comment: @cryptofish123 In C like syntax, ~ is a bitwise negation (it will negate every bit) not to be confused with a logical negation (!0 in C like world) which can eventually answer 0 or 1 (representing false and true respectively in most implementations in a language that does not distinguish booleans and integers).